# Xcode 11 removed my Fonts & Colors Theme from Xcode 10

Tags: xcode, xcode10, xcode11

My question is regarding the IDE in Xcode. For many versions, I was using a custom theme but Xcode 11 removed it from my themes and selected "Default (Dark)" after I installed it.

I was using a custom theme and I don't remember the settings. Would this still be stored somewhere that I could resurrect it in Xcode 11?

Answer (score 4):

Custom Fonts & Colors Themes are located in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes` - this folder is shared between different versions of Xcode.